# Can we easily avoid the "maximum supported lag is 350 error" when using the ARIMA function in R?

Tags: r, max

I am currently fitting a SARIMAX model to big data sets. Information is retrieved every 10 minutes, so I have a vector of size *52560* for a year of data. Considering it is representing electricity load in a device throughout said year, we can observe a daily pattern, a weekly one and a yearly one.

There is also a trend, so I need to differentiate my series 4 times. Since the set is for 1 year, I can let aside the yearly seasonality and focus on the other 3. Let's say I get something like this:

```
dauch = diff(diff(diff(auch2), 144), 1008)
```

With *144* being the daily seasonality (6×24 10-minute points per day) and *1008* the weekly one.
I would like to fit a SARIMAX model on which I worked with my predecessor. He found that SARIMAX(2,1,5)(1,2,8)144 was the best one for this series. However, I get an error whenever I try this:

```
themodel = arima(auch[1000:4024,1], order = c(2,1,5), seasonal = list(order = c(1,2,8), 
period = 144), xreg=tmpf[988:4012])
```

`tmpf` being the temperature used as an exogenous variable. The error is the following:

```
Error in makeARIMA(trarma[[1L]], trarma[[2L]], Delta, kappa, SSinit) : 
  maximum supported lag is 350
```

I don't really understand what it means in my case, because the period I chose is 144  which is inferior to 350. I feel like I need to keep the D = 2 in the model because of the dual differencing for daily and weekly pattern, but I don't know what to do to solve this. Thanks.